# Laravel - Vue JS Sibling component communication

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm NOT able to communicate b/w components using EventBus technique with Vue

```
Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue(); // Global event bus

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',
    data() {
        return {
            dailyData: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        'latest-feedbacks': LatestFeedbacks,
        'feedbacks-overview': FeedbacksOverview,
    }
});
```

In LatestFeedbacks.vue

```
...
created() {
     this.$eventBus.$emit('feedbacksChanged');
},
...
```

In FeedbacksOverview.vue

```
...
created() {
     this.$eventBus.$on('feedbacksChanged', ()=>{
        // code
     });
},
...
```

Comment: I don't see any major issue here. I [made a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxxvl47mn3) replicating what you're doing and it works fine.

Comment: The problem was that the Parent Vue instance needed some time to render the child components. I can't just go and straight away emit and listen within created hook of child components (siblings) when they are in the process of being rendered.

Comment: Then use `created` to mount the listener on one and `mounted` to broadcast the event on the other

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$root` instance to reach components outside the vertical chain.

Like this:

```
created() {
     this.$root.$emit('feedbacksChanged');
}

created() {
     this.$root.$on('feedbacksChanged', ()=>{
        // code
     });
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea for so many reasons; **do not do this**

Comment: Please explain why, I currently have this implemented so I'd like to refactor if it's poor practice.

Comment: From the vue docs: *In most cases, reaching into the parent makes your application more difficult to debug and understand, especially if you mutate data in the parent. When looking at that component later, it will be very difficult to figure out where that mutation came from.*

Comment: @DerekPollard how would you implement this?

Comment: I would personally probably just use vuex - OP looks like they are trying to supplement a global state with a global bus